# Populate multiple select drop down list from XML file using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, drop-down-menu, html-select

I've two dropdowns populating from an xml file using javascript.

Here is my xml date:

```
<root>
<DocTypes>
    <doctype>Protocols</doctype>
    <owngsite>CIMA</owngsite>
</DocTypes>
<DocTypes>
    <doctype>Form</doctype>
    <owngsite>EU Headquaters</owngsite>
</DocTypes>
<DocTypes>
    <doctype>Master Batch Record</doctype>
    <owngsite>France (Country Operations)</owngsite>
</DocTypes>
<DocTypes>
    <doctype>Method</doctype>
    <owngsite>Maisons-Alfort CDC</owngsite>
</DocTypes>
<DocTypes>
    <doctype>Policy</doctype>
    <owngsite>Malvern</owngsite>
</DocTypes>
<DocTypes>
    <doctype>Procedure</doctype>
    <owngsite>Salt Lake City</owngsite>
</DocTypes>
<DocTypes>
    <doctype>Specification</doctype>
    <owngsite>Mitry Mory</owngsite>
</DocTypes>
<DocTypes>
    <doctype>Standard</doctype>
    <owngsite>Nevers</owngsite>
</DocTypes>
<DocTypes>
    <doctype></doctype>
    <owngsite>Savigny Le Temple</owngsite>
</DocTypes>
<DocTypes>
    <doctype></doctype>
    <owngsite>Sens</owngsite>
</DocTypes>
<DocTypes>
    <doctype></doctype>
    <owngsite>WC-Frazer</owngsite>
</DocTypes>

</root>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
var xhr;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
}
/*else{
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); //code for IE6, IE5
}*/

xhr.open('GET','metaFiles/searchPage/js/docType.xml',true);
xhr.send();

window.onload = function()
{
    var x, xmldoc;
    xmldoc = xhr.responseXML;
    x = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("DocTypes");
    var select1 = document.getElementById("doctype");
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.text = "All";
    option.value = "empty";
    select1.add(option);
    var option2;
    //document.write(x.length);
    for (var i = 0; i <x.length; i++) 
    {
        option2 = document.createElement('option');
        option2.text = x[i].getElementsByTagName("doctype")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        option2.value = x[i].getElementsByTagName("doctype")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        select1.add(option2);
    }
    
    var select2 = document.getElementById("owngsite");
    var option4 = document.createElement('option');
    option4.text = "All";
    option4.value = "empty";
    select2.add(option4);
    var option3;
    for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++)
    {
        option3 = document.createElement('option');
        option3.text = x[i].getElementsByTagName("owngsite")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        option3.value = x[i].getElementsByTagName("owngsite")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        //document.write(x[i]);
        select2.add(option3);
            
    }

    return xhr;
}
```

The problem is my owning site list have more data than the doctype. So when I'm trying to skip the doctype data for the last three xml tags, I'm getting undefined error in javascript.
Is there anyway to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do realize that Java and JavaScript are completely unrelated, right?

Comment: Do you have anything valuable to contribute here? Yes, I totally understand both are different. I'm looking for a solution here be it using javascript or java. That's why the tag. Make no sense of downvoting just because of a tag. You could have simply edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at it a little differently. You want to fetch the text content of a list of nodes (by tag name) and filter empty and duplicate values.

```js
const sourceDocument = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(getXML(), 'text/xml');
addOptions(
  document.querySelector('#docTypeSelect'),
  sourceDocument.getElementsByTagName('doctype')
);
addOptions(
  document.querySelector('#siteSelect'),
  sourceDocument.getElementsByTagName('owngsite')
);

function addOptions(select, nodes) {
  const values = Array
    .from(nodes)
    // convert to string
    .map((node) => node.textContent.trim())
    // filter empty and duplicate values
    .filter(
      (value, index, self) => value !== '' && self.indexOf(value) === index
    );
  // remove all select child nodes
  select.textContent = '';
  // add the default
  let option = document.createElement('option');
  option.value = '';
  option.text = 'All';
  select.appendChild(option);
  // iterate values
  for (const value of values) {
    // add option
    option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = value;
    option.text = value;
    select.appendChild(option);
  }
}


function getXML() {
  return `<root>
<DocTypes>
    <doctype>Protocols</doctype>
    <owngsite>CIMA</owngsite>
</DocTypes>
<DocTypes>
    <doctype>Form</doctype>
    <owngsite>EU Headquaters</owngsite>
</DocTypes>
<DocTypes>
    <doctype>Master Batch Record</doctype>
    <owngsite>France (Country Operations)</owngsite>
</DocTypes>
<DocTypes>
    <doctype>Method</doctype>
    <owngsite>Maisons-Alfort CDC</owngsite>
</DocTypes>
<DocTypes>
    <doctype>Policy</doctype>
    <owngsite>Malvern</owngsite>
</DocTypes>
<DocTypes>
    <doctype>Procedure</doctype>
    <owngsite>Salt Lake City</owngsite>
</DocTypes>
<DocTypes>
    <doctype>Specification</doctype>
    <owngsite>Mitry Mory</owngsite>
</DocTypes>
<DocTypes>
    <doctype>Standard</doctype>
    <owngsite>Nevers</owngsite>
</DocTypes>
<DocTypes>
    <doctype></doctype>
    <owngsite>Savigny Le Temple</owngsite>
</DocTypes>
<DocTypes>
    <doctype></doctype>
    <owngsite>Sens</owngsite>
</DocTypes>
<DocTypes>
    <doctype></doctype>
    <owngsite>WC-Frazer</owngsite>
</DocTypes>

</root>
`;
}
```

```html
<select id="docTypeSelect"></select>
<select id="siteSelect"></select>
```